# Is there a way we can print prepared statement as a string with all the placeholders replaces with its actual values

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way we can print prepared statement as a string with all the placeholders replaces with its actual values

1. I'm using Oracle 11g and Java 1.6
2. Using log4j packages for logging

Comment: There are probably many, how are you executing your sql queries? (Hibernate? plain JDBC?)

Comment: I'm using a plain JDBC

Comment: What we really need is a method that will let us obtain the query string with parameter placeholders replaced with actual values. Because java.sql.PreparedStatement has no such method we have to implement one ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Oracle's JDBC driver, you will get `OraclePreparedStatement` object when you call `connection.preparedStatement(sql)`. [Here's](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.html) the javadoc for it and as it does not override `toString()` method,  you will see a `hash` of the object on calling `toString()` (default implementation).

In this case, the only option is to write your own method that accepts `String` sql and `parameters` and prints pretty `String`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
```

Maybe you can describe better what you have in your project for get better answers

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing the query and expect that you'll have a definite ResultSet then the following call ResultSet's `getStatement()` method will definitely help.

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
String executedQuery = resultSet.getStatement().toString();
```

You either use `System.out.println(executedQuery)` or `log4J` as you state, that's your choice of implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got the below output: INFO: 
[UCaaSReportsUtil] : getServiceReportData: executedQuery oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@98644313

This is nothing but preparedSTatement.toString()

Answer (score 0):

As you are using plain jdbc with Oracle driver, I will try a configuration similar to the one described in this oracle post:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm

Another thing you can do is install JProfiler, there is a Database configuration there that you can use to trace every call that your application is doing to your database.

You also can set the log4j property that was described in another response. If you do it this way, remember to set the log4j root logger into TRACE/DEBUG mode.